# Filtered list of files with grep, forward that list of files to grep further

Tags: regex, filter, grep

I have a list of filtered files found by `grep` by a specific regex, but want to use the results of *that filtered list of files* to further `grep` those results only.

Filtering a Magento 2 code base for file names only: `grep -Ril` (-i only because I tried to use extra filtering on regex)

```
 grep -Ril 'catalog_product_index_eav' vendor/


vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Layer/Filter/Decimal.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Indexer/Eav/Decimal.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/db_schema.xml
vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/db_schema_whitelist.json
vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Integrity/_files/dependency_test/tables_ce.php
vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Indexer/Eav/SourceTest.php
vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Search/FilterMapper/StockStatusFilterWithFullFilterTest.php
vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Search/FilterMapper/StockStatusFilterWithGeneralFilterTest.php
vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Search/FilterMapper/CustomAttributeFilterTest.php
vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Search/FilterMapper/VisibilityFilterTest.php
vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Adapter/Mysql/BaseSelectStrategy/BaseSelectAttributesSearchStrategyTest.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Search/FilterMapper/VisibilityFilter.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Search/FilterMapper/CustomAttributeFilter.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Search/FilterMapper/TermDropdownStrategy/SelectBuilder.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Filter/Preprocessor.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Adapter/Mysql/BaseSelectStrategy/BaseSelectAttributesSearchStrategy.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Aggregation/DataProvider/QueryBuilder.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Aggregation/DataProvider/SelectBuilderForAttribute.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Test/Unit/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Aggregation/DataProvider/QueryBuilderTest.php
vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog-search/Test/Integration/Model/Search/FilterMapper/TermDropdownStrategy/ApplyStockConditionToSelectOnDefaultStockTest.php
vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog-search/Test/Integration/Model/Search/FilterMapper/TermDropdownStrategy/ApplyStockConditionToSelectTest.php
vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog-search/Test/Integration/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Aggregation/DataProvider/ApplyStockConditionToSelectWithDefaultStockTest.php
vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog-search/Test/Integration/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Aggregation/DataProvider/ApplyStockConditionToSelectTest.php
vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog-search/Test/_files/clean_catalog_product_index_eav_table.php
```

Trying to add `function` as *testing my regex results* into the regex however doesn't return any results:

```
grep -Ril 'catalog_product_index_eav.*function.*' vendor/
grep -Ril 'catalog_product_index_eav.*.*function.*' vendor/
```

Either I need to be able to to handle the regex better which is not returning anything (`function` keyword is just something that I test with since it should be returning at least something) or better:

> How do I forward the result names to further filter:

I want to do something like this then on those filtered file names:

```
grep -Ril 'catalog_product_index_eav' vendor/ | grep 'function`
OR
grep -Ril 'catalog_product_index_eav' vendor/ | grep 'function` [$filename]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting to `awk` script to `AND` operation  on RegExp (actually any logical expression of one or more RegExp).

```
 awk '/regExp-pattern-1/ && /regExp-pattern-2/ {print FILENAME}' RS="&@&@&@&@" files-1 file-2 ...
```

The advantage of this approach: every file is scanned only once. And every file is scanned as a single record (`grep` is scanning line by line).

The disadvantages: RegExp patterns in `awk` are case sensitive. And `awk` takes list of files only (no recursive folders).

#### As for pure `grep`

Suggesting to nest `grep` commands.

```
 grep -il "regExp-pattern-2" $(grep -irl "regExp-pattern-1" folder-path)
```

Comment: The `grep` is already partially useful thanks!
As for `awk` `files1 file-2` arguments at the end; does that support `folder/`s?

Comment: correct `awk` requires list of files only. It is possible to use `find` command: such as. `awk 'script' variables $(find /folder-path -type f)`.

Comment: Ok yeah that makes sense now, combining `find` to get the list of files required for `awk`.  For my personal use, `grep` you nested does what I need mostly (I will try to filter further).  Thanks so much!

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS and GNU grep for recursive searching. You can make regexp comparisons case-insensitive in GNU awk by setting `IGNORECASE=1` just like you do for grep with `-i` or with any awk just do `tolower($0) ~ /lower-case-regexp/`. IMHO  no-one should be using grep for a recursive search since `find` already exists to do that job - the GNU guys screwed up by giving grep similar functionality.

Comment: I just realised you're using `RS="&@&@&@&@"` to get gawk to read the whole file into memory at once. That obviously would fail if the string `RS="&@&@&@&@"` appeared in any of the input files. That's unlikely of course but you don't need to do that, just set `RS="^$"` and you're guaranteed nothing in a non-empty input file can match it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use grep to find files. Use `find` to **find** files and `grep` to **g/re/p** (**G**lobally match a **R**egular **E**xpression and **P**rint the results) within files. There are subtle clues in the tools' names as to their intended purpose!

In this case, though, what you apparently want to do within a file (match strings on different lines) is more than a simple g/re/p so then we turn to awk.

It sounds like this is what you're trying to do, using GNU find for `+` and GNU awk for `IGNORECASE` and `nextfile`, and without reading the whole of each file into memory (as that could fail given a huge input file and is inefficient if the matches strings occur early in the file):

```
find vendor -type f -exec \
    awk -v IGNORECASE=1 'FNR==1{x=y=0} /catalog_product_index_eav/{x=1} /function/{y=1} x && y{print FILENAME; nextfile}' {} +
```

If you didn't have GNU tools you could do the same less efficiently with:

```
find vendor -type f -exec \
    awk '{lc=tolower($0)} lc ~ /catalog_product_index_eav/{x=1} lc ~ /function/{y=1} x && y{print FILENAME; exit}' {} \;
```